# Refresh ClaimsPrincipal after HttpContext.SignInAsync (without identity)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims, cookie-authentication

I'm building a ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app. I am not using Identity. I am using CookieAuthentication.

Instead, I sign-in the user using [HttContext.SignInAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L112-L113):

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, myGeneratedClaimsPrincipal)
```

When something in the principal changes, I have to sign-out and sign-in to refresh the principal.

In there a way I can refresh the principal without sign-out/sign-in?

Comment: No. This question is asked constantly, and I'm sure I can easily find a dupe. Long and short, this is how claims work. They are part of the actual principal that's the result of the authentication process and it is that principal that is persisted to prevent having to sign in over and over. As such, the only way to refresh the claims is to refresh the principal, which happens via logging out and logging back in.

Comment: https://aspnetcore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security/authentication/cookie.html#reacting-to-back-end-changes this seems to suggest `context.ReplacePrincipal()` could be used though @ChrisPratt?

Comment: seems to be even used in Identity: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/95ab2fa4af43c552bb05a83f3cc4916a51c33744/src/Identity/Core/src/SecurityStampValidator.cs#L62-L82

Comment: That has to do with security stamp validation, which is used to control the auth cookie persistence. For example, if you changed something and you need that to be updated in the cookie, then you can add a check for this during validation to determine whether the cookie should be updated. This does achieve what you're looking for in principle, but the process only runs when the validation interval has expired - it is not immediate.

Comment: You can make it more immediate by lowering the interval, but then you incur more DB queries from constantly validating the security stamp.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So if I change a role for a user, they will have to wait until the refresh interval to have that role refreshed in their cookie. Otherwise, they can sign-out/in. And if I really want the change to be immediate, I could create some custom method to manually replace the principal by using `context.ReplacePrincipal()`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, except for that last bit. That method exists on a context object that's created as part of this security stamp validation process. As such, you can't just "manually" use it whenever you want: only within the context of validating the security stamp. If you want immediate, your best bet is to sign the user out and back in programmatically, i.e. it doesn't require their intervention. That's totally doable, but it must be done in the context of a request by that user (which may not work for your needs).

Comment: Oh, ReplacePrinicpal is only for CookieValidatePrincipalContext. Darn. I see what you mean. Yeah, I guess I could create a middleware to do the programmatic sign-out-and-back-in - but in order to determine when to perform the sign-out-in, I'd probably have to read from the database...which is basically like the security stamp with refresh interval of 0...back to square one. I'll just live with the 30 minute interval for now. Thanks!